# Как сделать перенос элементов списка при уменьшии экрана, чтобы сначала переносились 2 элемента <li>, затем (при большем уменьшении окна) каждый <li>?

Tags: css, list, flexbox, css-grid

```
             <div class="sect0__content0">
                <ul class="sect0__content sect0-list">
                    <li class="sect0-list__item">
                        <p>Биокомьютер</p>
                        <p>Что такое биотехнология?</p>
                    <li class="sect0-list__item">
                        <p>Истории технологии</p>
                        <p>Кто изобрел первые модели?</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sect0-list__item">
                        <p>Проблемы технологии</p>
                        <p>В чем сложность изобретений?</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="sect0-list__item">
                        <p>Перспективы</p>
                        <p>Какие приоритеты развития?</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/companies/edison/articles/344878/ развлекайтесь :3